# c# WebApi OData complex type is always null in post ODataRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

My problem is that "siteSetup" is always null for the following odata action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("Setup")]
public IHttpActionResult Setup(SiteSetup siteSetup)
{
    return BadRequest("Not yet working");
}
```

This is my complex type

```
public class SiteSetup
{
    public SiteSetup()
    {
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string CompanyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And this is the fiddler for a request.

[image]

Comment: Is `SiteSetup` a complex type or an entity? You don't have controllers for complex types, there is nothing that you can do with them in isolation, they have to be used as properties on entities and your controller accepts an entity.

Comment: @ben-robinson It was supposed to be an complex type to be used only in this action. But if thats' not allowed I will have to solve this another way. Thanks. You can post this as answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Action with complextype as parameter is support in OData/WebApi V4, you may use `ODataActionParameters` in your controller method, you can see this page for instruction, http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support